# Grouping a generic list via LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to take a collection and group it via Linq but all the examples I've seen fail in some manner or other with some syntax difference that I can't quite lick.

My collection:

```
Dim a As New List(Of ProcessAlert)
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Alert", 2))
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Document", 2))
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Note", 2))
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Alert", 1))
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Document", 1))
  a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Note", 1))
Return a
```

I need to turn this collection into a simple way to give this final outcome:

```
"5551110000@txt.att.net", "Alert, Document, Note"
"jdoe@home.com", "Alert, Document, Note"
```

Here's the definition of the `ProcessAlert` class:

```
Public Class ProcessAlert
  Public LoanNumber As String
  Public EmailAddress As String
  Public AlertType As String
  Public AlertMethodID As Byte
End Class
```

Thanks in advance,

CD

I've managed to convert to VB:

```
    Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(i) i.EmailAddress).Select(Function(g) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(g.Key, String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType).ToArray())))
```

Now how do I add in to group by LoanNumber and Email Address so that my result is:
        "0000112367","jdoe@home.com", "Alert, Document, Note"

Comment: Can you give the definition of the `ProcessAlert` structure, and its constructor?

Comment: Public Class ProcessAlert
    Public LoanNumber As String
    Public EmailAddress As String
    Public AlertType As String
    Public AlertMethodID As Byte
End Class

Comment: Edited your question to add the definition you gave me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the linq code I would write (in c# - sorry I couldn't complete it in VB)

```
var res = a.GroupBy(i=>i.EmailAddress )
    .Select(g=> new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                    g.Key, 
                    string.Join(",", g.Select(x=> x.AlertType ).ToArray()) 
            ));
```

This will give you the output you want in a collection of KeyValuePair

in order to group them by both LoadNumber and EmailAddress this would be the c# code:

```
var res = alerts
    .GroupBy(a => new { L = a.LoanNumber, E = a.EmailAddress })
    .Select(a => new
        {
            LoadNumber = a.Key.L,
            EmailAddress = a.Key.E,
            Types = string.Join(", ", a.Select(x => x.AlertType).ToArray())
        }).ToList();
```

where result is a List of a Complext type {LoadNumber, EmailAddress, Types}

Comment: Third param is string that I'm concatenating and sending as part of a body. so it would be EmailAddress as Sending to, "Alert, Note, Document" as the Body of the message

Comment: How would I add in a 2nd field for grouping? I placed the VB conversion above

Comment: Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(g) New With {Key .A = g.LoanNumber, Key .B = g.EmailAddress})

Comment: That gives me both groupings but the keyvaluepair is lost do to adding that, Ugh!

Comment: When you say GroupBy(x=> AAA), then when you say .Select(g=>...), g.Key would be of type of the return value of AAA. So in your amended case, it would be a complex type. so you can say for example: g.Key.A and so on...

Comment: I'm not quite following you there... sorry

Comment: Instead of returning a KeyValuePair I tried a New List(Of MyComplexttype)(value1, value2, value3) but that wouldn't work

Comment: I tried this which won't compile.. it looks like it would be right:

         Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(i) New With {Key .A = i.LoanNumber, Key .B = i.EmailAddress}).Select(Function(g) New List(Of EmailAlert)(g.Key.A, g.Key.B, String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType).ToArray())))

Comment: Where Complex Type EmailAlert is defined as

Friend Class EmailAlert
    Public LoanNumber As String
    Public EmailAddress As String
    Public Alerts As String
End Class

Comment: New List(Of MyComplexttype)(value1, value2, value3) doesn't make sense to me, what structure do you want the output?

Comment: Using your first example this is what I imagined it would be
Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(i) New With {Key .A = i.LoanNumber, Key .B = i.EmailAddress}).Select(Function(g) New List(Of EmailAlert)(LoanNumber = g.Key.A, EmailAddress = g.Key.B, AlertType = String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType))))

But there's something wrong with that too..

I want my output to look like:
"0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Alert, Document, Note"
"0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Alert, Document, Note"

You see, those 2 rows represent the list of data at the top of my post

Comment: ... Group By LoanNumber, EmailAddress and Concatenate the AlertTypes into one field....

Comment: see my new notes added to answer above. Hope it can help

Comment: I managed a pipe delimited output by doing:
Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(i) i.LoanNumber & "| " & i.EmailAddress & "| ").Select(Function(g) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(g.Key, String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType).ToArray())))

Comment: True, but it won't work when you need a structured output (i.e. having EmailAddress and LoadNumber as Properties)

Comment: The example you gave above looked like it was going to do the trick but didn't, the output I get from it looks like:
LoanNumber="0000112367", EmailAddress="jdoe@home.com", AlertType="Note"
LoanNumber="0000112367", EmailAddress="jdoe@home.com", AlertType="Document"
LoanNumber="0000112367", EmailAddress="jdoe@home.com", AlertType="Alert"

And then repeats for the 2nd email address.. the AlertTypes didn't concatenate... leaves me right where I started

Comment: Dim res = Alerts _
                  .GroupBy(Function(a) New With {.L = a.LoanNumber, .E = a.EmailAddress}) _
                  .Select(Function(a) New With {.LoanNumber = a.Key.L, .EmailAddress = a.Key.E, _
                                               .AlertType = String.Join(", ", a.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType).ToArray())}).ToList()

Comment: No it doesn't, the output I get is correct, you may have made a mistake converting it to VB, output I get is this: (0000112367 - 5551110000@txt.att.net - Alert, Document, Note) 
(0000112367 - jdoe@home.com - Alert, Document, Note)

Comment: well dang it! I would rather be doing the c# method but am restricted to Vb. I think lambdas have some limitations in vb really. Thanks for all your help...

Comment: Cheers :) - anyway you can mark this as answer if you think it is! Good luck

Comment: Hi guys, please try to avoid dumping a lot of useful contents into comments. Comments are supposed to be minor feedback, not really important information. Please edit the appropriate parts into the question and/or answer.

Comment: Hi Lasse, thanks for the point, but I have already updated my answer and included useful codes of this conversation.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first attempt at getting help via SO. It just made sense to add to the thread with the accumulated knowledge. Sorry.

Comment: Caveat is that the answer marked works in C# but was unable to get it working in VB.NET. Ended up using my pipe delimited option